# Why does dataclass favour __repr__ over __str__?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Given the following code, I think output `(A)` makes sense since `__str__` takes precedence over `__repr__` however I am a bit confused about output `(B)` why does it favour `__repr__` over `__str__` and is there a way to make the class use the `__str__` rather than the `__repr__` of `Foo` without defining `__str__` for `Bar`?

```py
@dataclass()
class Foo():    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "Foo::__repr__"
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Foo::__str__"

@dataclass()
class Bar():   
    foo: Foo

f = Foo()
b = Bar(f)

print(f)  # (A) Outputs: Foo::__str__ 
print(b)  # (B) Outputs: Bar(foo=Foo::__repr__)
```

I stumbled upon this because I saw that my custom `__str__` of `Foo` was not being used by `Bar` in fact even if I remove the `__repr__` output `(B)` will still be `Bar(foo=Foo())` instead of `Bar(foo=Foo::__str__)`.

Comment: It might make sense to focus on the "how" question rather than the "why" question -- [the "why" question is arguably off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design), because understanding _why_ a design decision you disagree with was made doesn't solve any narrow, specific problem encountered in the practice of software development.

Comment: For the first part of the question, see: [Why does printing a tuple (list, dict, etc.) in Python double the backslashes?](/q/29245234/4518341), [What is the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`?](/q/1436703/4518341)

Comment: For the second part of the question, *"is there a way to make the class use the `__str__` rather than the `__repr__` of `Foo` without defining `__str__` for `Bar`?"*, why do you want that? If you want `Bar` to have a more end-user-friendly `__str__`, you'll need to write it yourself ofc. Are you aware that `str(b)` defaults to `repr(b)` since the class doesn't have a `__str__`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal for the repr to be preferred to str when rendering a representation within a container of some sort, e.g.:

```
>>> print(f)
Foo::__str__
>>> print([f])
[Foo::__repr__]
```

It is necessary for repr to be *unambiguous*, for example to see the difference between numbers and strings here:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class D:
...     s: str
...     n: int
... 
>>> D('1', 1)
D(s='1', n=1)
```

I think you should not override `Foo.__repr__` in that way, because you're straying from the "unwritten rule" that [`eval(repr(obj)) == obj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

Comment: ..._is_ it unwritten? I vaguely recall it being explicitly written (somewhere back in the 2.x era) that when one _couldn't_ obey that convention, it was appropriate to use arrow brackets to make it explicit that what was being emitted wasn't eval'able.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the docs only say _"For many types, this function makes an attempt to [do that] ..."_ and doesn't explicitly offer any guidance suggesting user-defined types should do the same.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think there is such rule, for instance sklearn does not obey the first rule mentioned by Charles, but neither uses square brackets in its repr `repr(PCA().fit(np.random.randn(10,10)))` gives `PCA()` which does not contain the fitted state.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default convention for containers. It's analogous to the way lists, tuples, and dictionaries work -- they use `repr()` for the element values.